# How to Overwrite the DisplayFunction?

Tags: display

How to overwrite the display function of `TemplateBox`? For example, if I have:

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],  ToBoxes@Quantity[3, "Meters"]]
```

how do I overwrite the `DisplayFunction` to make the out put display differently, without changing the actual value of the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boxes are just like any other expression when they are evaluated by the kernel, so one way to achieve this is with replacement rules:

```
ToBoxes@Quantity[3, "Meters"] /.
  (DisplayFunction -> _) -> (DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{#1, " метра"} &)) // RawBoxes
```

> 3 метра